# insert words and count in 2 dimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of country names and I want to create 2 dimensional array of the names and there count. The array i have is,

```
names = [Afghanistan,Alaska,Alaska,Alaska,Alaska,Alaska,Argentina,Argentina,British Virgin Islands,British Virgin Islands]
```

So i want the count of each country in 2 dimensional array. for example i need something like this

```
country['Afghanistan, 1]
country['Alaska, 5]
country['Argentina, 2]
```

and so on.

Could someone please help. Thanks

Comment: Is this your _actual_ code?

Comment: yes, the names array is actual array i am getting

Comment: I don't see how that's possible - unless you have defined the `Afganistan`, `Alaska` (and so on) variables, this would be a `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you asked for:

```
var nameCounts = {};
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if(names[i] in nameCounts) {
        nameCounts[names[i]]++;
    } else {
        nameCounts[names[i]] = 1;
    }
}

var country = [];
for(var name in nameCounts) {
    country.push([name, nameCounts[name]]);
}
```

Though if I were you, I would stop once I had populated `nameCounts`, which is a map from name to count.

Also, you could optimize this if you knew the name were in alphabetical order, like in your example.

Comment: thanks I think i got the idea. I try to sort it alphabetically and try to optimize this.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I just meant that it could be done differently if it were, but don't bother to sort it if it isn't already. Just use the answer above and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
names = ["Afghanistan","Alaska","Alaska","Alaska","Alaska","Alaska","Argentina","Argentina","British Virgin Islands","British     Virgin Islands"];

function countWords(o,n){
    o[n]=(o[n])?o[n]+1:1;
    return o; 
};

function makeTuples(obj){
    var tuples=[];
    for(var i in obj){
        tuples.push([i, obj[i]])
    }
    return tuples;
}
console.log(makeTuples(names.reduce(countWords, {})))
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMRb7/1/) to play with.

For documentation about `Array.reduce()` take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Older browsers, which do not support `Array.reduce()` should work with the corresponding implementation in [UnderscoreJs](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that creates the result array directly:

```
function getNamesCount(a) {
  var nameIndex = {};
  var results = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=a.length, name; i<iLen; i++) {
    name = a[i];

    if (!nameIndex.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      nameIndex[name] = results.length;
      results.push(name, 0);
    }
    results[nameIndex[name] + 1] += 1;
  }
  return results;
}
```